# How to fix the broken line in a colored image?

Tags: python, image, opencv

I was trying to do some image processing task on a screenshot of google map. After some processing, I have got some broken lines like this:

[image: google map screenshot after some processing]

Now, I want to connect the gaps in the image according to the color of both sides

Comment: I guess one idea is to define the lines with 3 points, then get their "thickness", then run some sort of clustering (k-means?) on the colors, then fill in the black regions with the enclosing region. It doesn't work so well if the black holes share multiple color boundaries though.

Comment: Could you add your original input and expected output image?